# Get Current Browser URL without Selenium Python

Tags: python, url

Hello I want to ask if there is a way to get my current url every second printed without the selenium library in Python. Selenium would be probably the easier way i know but this is not in my interests. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what are you trying to do, exactly? If you just want to get a request from the url you are talking about.. You can use the **requests** library.

To make a request, simply do:

```
import requests

with requests.get('https://url.com') as response:
    print(response)
```

If the output is `Response[200]`, you're good.